# Update Column value from different column in the same table based on different row

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

**Database : Oracle**

I like to update a column ClientCode value "30" to "40" based on following condition:

If a.Newcode (12.1.1) = b.Old_code(12.1.1)
and b.new_code is null

I have tried the following query but no success so far;

```
UPDATE CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING a 

SET a.CLIENTCODE = (SELECT B.CLIENTCODE FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING b 

                        WHERE b.NEW_CODE IS NULL
                            AND b.PROJECTCODE = A.PROJECTCODE
                                AND b.OLD_CODE = a.NEW_CODE)
WHERE a.PROJECTCODE = 2242

AND a.NEW_CODE IS NOT NULL

AND A.NEW_CODE IN (SELECT c.OLD_CODE FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING c where c.new_code is null and c.old_code = a.new_code)
```

Comment: Any error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Check Constraint error on column ClientCode. ClientCode can't be NULL. I think my inner query returns no row.

Comment: I don't understand the if statement. is it not b.new_code code is null instead?

Comment: Marc, you are right. Sorry it is b.new_code is null. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add the correlated subquery to the `where` clause as well:

```
UPDATE CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING a 
    SET a.CLIENTCODE = (SELECT B.CLIENTCODE
                        FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING b 
                        WHERE b.NEW_CODE IS NULL AND b.PROJECTCODE = A.PROJECTCODE AND
                              b.OLD_CODE = a.NEW_CODE
                       )
    WHERE a.PROJECTCODE = 2242 AND a.NEW_CODE IS NOT NULL and
          A.NEW_CODE IN (SELECT c.OLD_CODE FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING c where c.new_code is null and c.old_code = a.new_code) and
          exists (SELECT B.CLIENTCODE
                  FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING b 
                  WHERE b.NEW_CODE IS NULL AND b.PROJECTCODE = A.PROJECTCODE AND
                        b.OLD_CODE = a.NEW_CODE
                 )
```

Another is to use `coalesce()` to keep the same value when the new one would be `NULL`:

```
UPDATE CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING a 
    SET a.CLIENTCODE = coalesce((SELECT B.CLIENTCODE
                                 FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING b 
                                 WHERE b.NEW_CODE IS NULL AND b.PROJECTCODE = A.PROJECTCODE AND
                                       b.OLD_CODE = a.NEW_CODE
                                ), a.clientcode)
    WHERE a.PROJECTCODE = 2242 AND a.NEW_CODE IS NOT NULL and
          A.NEW_CODE IN (SELECT c.OLD_CODE FROM CLIENTACTIVITYCODEMAPPING c where c.new_code is null and c.old_code = a.new_code)
```